# XMPPIQ doesn't set vCard tag in the vCard

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework, vcf-vcard

I am trying to retrieve vCards for few JIDs, including the current user. I initialized and activated `XMPPvCardTempModule` using following code -

```
_xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
_xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:self.xmppvCardStorage];
_xmppvCardAvatarModule = [[XMPPvCardAvatarModule alloc] initWithvCardTempModule:self.xmppvCardTempModule];
[self.xmppvCardTempModule           activate:self.xmppStream];
[self.xmppvCardAvatarModule         activate:self.xmppStream];
[self.xmppvCardAvatarModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
[self.xmppvCardTempModule addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

And then I implemented the following delegate methods -

```
- (void)xmppvCardTempModule:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule
        didReceivevCardTemp:(XMPPvCardTemp *)vCardTemp
                     forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid{
    DDLogDebug(@"Received vCard for %@ \n vCard:%@",jid.full,vCardTemp.XMLString);
    ContactCore* contact = [appDelegate.coreDataController findContact:jid.user];
    contact.vCard = vCardTemp;
    [appDelegate.dataController postContactUpdateNotification:contact];
}
- (void)xmppvCardTempModuleDidUpdateMyvCard:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule{
    [self.selfContact setVCard:vCardTempModule.myvCardTemp];
}
- (void)xmppvCardTempModule:(XMPPvCardTempModule *)vCardTempModule failedToUpdateMyvCard:(DDXMLElement *)error{
    DDLogDebug(@"failedToUpdateMyvCard Error: %@",error.XMLString);
}

-(void)xmppvCardAvatarModule:(XMPPvCardAvatarModule *)vCardTempModule didReceivePhoto:(UIImage *)photo forJID:(XMPPJID *)jid{
    ContactCore* contact = [appDelegate.coreDataController findContact:jid.user];
}
```

The problem is that none of these delegate methods ever gets called. I can see the vCard output in the Log data which means that the vCards are getting fetched properly. So I implemented `didReceiveIQ` to get the vCards directly from the source, using the following code -

```
- (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream*)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq{
    XMPPvCardTemp *vCard = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempSubElementFromIQ:iq];
    if(vCard){
        ContactCore* contact = [appDelegate.coreDataController findContact:iq.from.user];
        contact.vCard = vCard;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

But the `vCard` never gets initialized. I checked the IQs and I was receiving them properly. Then I checked the whole XML properly and found out that the `vCard` tag was absent and it was replaced with the actual name of the contact. For example this is what I was getting for one of the contact -

```
<iq
    xmlns="jabber:client" from="xxx@xxx.com" to="xxx@xxx.com/xxx" id="12345" type="result">
    <Abhi
        xmlns="vcard-temp" prodid="-//HandGen//NONSGML vGen v1.0//EN" version="2.0">
        <PHOTO>
            <TYPE>image/jpeg</TYPE>
            <BINVAL><!--A long Base64 code--></BINVAL>
        </PHOTO>
    </Abhi>
</iq>
```

The tag `<Abhi>` should be `<vCard>` for the `vCardTempSubElementFromIQ` method to identify it as a `vCard`. I want to know if it's a normal behavior or is there something I am doing wrong here? If it's something I am doing wrong, what should be the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While saving a vCard I was using `name` property of the `vCard` to set name of the contact. This property actually changes the tag name, not the contact name. I started using `nickname` property after realizing my mistake.